# How to remove the box around the code-block in reStructuredText with sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am using restructured text to document something. To use directive "code-block", the code seems always to be contained in a box in the generated document. For example,

```
     .. code-block:: C++
        :linenos:
        :emphasize-lines: 2

        void readIntegerFile(const string& fileName, vector<int>& dest)
            throw(invalid_argument, runtime_error)
        {
            // some code ...
        }
```

The C++ code is alway boxed in generated PDF file. I am wondering if there is a knob to turn off the box. I googled around and can't find it. In fact, I can't even find the full list of knobs of *code-block*

Thanks

Comment: How do you go from reST to PDF?

Comment: Inside a console, run 'make latexpdf'. But u need to setup it through sphinx-quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your conf.py file

```
latex_elements = {
    'sphinxsetup': 'verbatimwithframe=false',
}
```

This will work no matter what your background color is

Answer (score 2):

The box seems to be hardcoded, but you can hide it by adding this command to 
`latex_elements['preamble']` in the `conf.py` file:

```
\definecolor{VerbatimBorderColor}{rgb}{1,1,1}
```

This won't work very well if you don't have plain white background though.